# force unused parameter for macro

Tags: c, macros, x-macros

### Simple idea:

I'm using X-macros to define command list structure and declare command callbacks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COMMAND_LIST(X) \
        X(toto_all) \
        X(help) \
        //end of list

typedef void (*callback_t)(int a, int b);

typedef struct 
{
    char * name;    
    callback_t callback;
}command_t;


#define CALLBACK_DEC(COMMAND_NAME)  void _##COMMAND_NAME(int a, int b);
COMMAND_LIST(CALLBACK_DEC)

#define COMMAND_DEF(COMMAND_NAME)  { #COMMAND_NAME, & _##COMMAND_NAME },
static command_t commands[] =
{
  COMMAND_LIST(COMMAND_DEF)
};

#define COMMAND(COMMAND_NAME,CODE)          void _##COMMAND_NAME(int A, int B) {  CODE  }

COMMAND(toto_all,
    printf("helloworld\n");
)

COMMAND(help,
    printf("help!\n");
)

int main()
{
    commands[0].callback(1,2);
    commands[1].callback(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

it works.

> helloworld
>   help!

---

### Adding some parameters:

If you change the first command list to this (by adding parameters)

```
#define COMMAND_LIST(X) \
        X(toto_all,         1,      3,      5) \
        X(help,             0,      0,      0) \
        //end of list

typedef struct 
{
    callback_t callback;
    char * name;  
    int arg_min; 
    int arg_max;
    int arg_num;
}command_t;
```

then, when running it I get the following error:

```
macro "CALLBACK_DEC" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1
```

I have to use all the parameters for the command list definition (command declaration):

```
#define COMMAND_DEF(COMMAND_NAME, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM)  (command_t){ #COMMAND_NAME, & _##COMMAND_NAME, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM},
```

but it's quite tricky to now use it for the callback declaration...

**Is there a clever way for this X-macro to avoid this error?**

---

#### I thought about the non-macro way to mask unused parameters:

which is by using `(void)param;`,
which gives the ugly

```
#define CALLBACK_DEC(COMMAND_NAME, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM) void _##COMMAND_NAME(int a, int b); void(ARG_MIN); void(ARG_MAX);  void(ARG_NUM)
```

and this does not work...I get a strange:

```
main.c:27:20: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
         X(toto_all,0,0,0) \
```

---

#### I think there is another way:

maybe using something like this...

```
#define COMMAND_LIST(X,Y) \
        X(Y(toto_all,         0,      0,      0)) \
        X(Y(help,             0,      0,      0)) \
        //command name,    arg min, arg max, arg num, string?
        //end of list

typedef void (*callback_t)(int a, int b);

typedef struct 
{
    char * name;    
    callback_t callback;
}command_t;

#define GET_ONLY_NAME(COMMAND_NAME1, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM) COMMAND_NAME1
#define CALLBACK_DEC(COMMAND_NAME)  void _##COMMAND_NAME(int a, int b);
COMMAND_LIST(CALLBACK_DEC,GET_ONLY_NAME);
#undef CALLBACK_DEC

#define GET_FULL_LIST(X) X
#define COMMAND_DEF(COMMAND_NAME, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM)  (command_t){ #COMMAND_NAME, & _##COMMAND_NAME, ARG_MIN, ARG_MAX, ARG_NUM},
static command_t commands[] =
{
  COMMAND_LIST(COMMAND_DEF,GET_FULL_LIST)
};
#undef COMMAND_DEF
```

but I still get the following strange error, there is a problem in the expansion but i can't see where...

```
main.c:27:31: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
         X(Y(toto_all,         0,      0,      0)) \
```

***Maybe the truth is elsewhere... :)***

any hints?

Comment: The "it works" version doesn't work. You have a semicolon here: `COMMAND_LIST(CALLBACK_DEC);` but also in the macro declaration above it. Furthermore, you can't use compound literals to initialize a file scope variable since that's not a constant expression. (Just drop the compound literal notation and it works.) Which compiler and what non-standard setup is required to compile the code?

Comment: just copy paste the first code and you'll see it works: https://onlinegdb.com/SyABNE-NL

Comment: Ok so default GNU C. Might want to make a habit of compiling with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` and you'll find various bugs and syntax errors that the GNU C version hides.

Comment: thanx, corrected in the post. This does not answer the question though :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a an issue with X macros overall - you have to write a macro accepting all parameters, even when you are just using a few.

In your case you pass the specific macro as a parameter to the list, so you can add some flexibility there. Using variadic macros might solve the problem. You should be able to do like this:

```
#define COMMAND_DEF(COMMAND_NAME, ...)  { #COMMAND_NAME, & _##COMMAND_NAME },
...
COMMAND_LIST(COMMAND_DEF)
```

Where you only explicitly name the parameters that this particular macro is interested in, then let the rest of them go into the `...` part which is then ignored.

This does however build in a dependency in the data, because it only allows you to expand parameters from left to right, so to speak. So for

```
X(toto_all,         1,      3,      5,      "-")
```

you can write a macro that uses just `toto_all`, or `toto_all` and `1`, but you would't be able write a macro that just uses for example `1` and `3`. For such special cases I believe you will still have to name all macro parameters.

Yet another option is self-documenting code:

```
#define COMMAND_DEF(COMMAND_NAME, ignored1, FOO, ignored2, ignored3) \
/* do stuff with COMMAND NAME and FOO only */
```